# Comma separated list containing section names

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a possibility to, instead of printing a large list containing the table of contents, process to .toc as a list that fits on a few lines?

By this I mean, instead of:

```
1  First section                                   1
2  Second section                                  1
3  Test section                                    2
```

to get a line saying

```
First section, Second section, Test section
```

or even better, if that is possible:

```
Page 1: First section, second section, Page 2: Test section
```

I haven't been able to find a package that does this for me, have I overlooked one or does this involve more serious coding?

Note: if there's also subsections in the document, they should be ignored. In a regular ToC, I'd set tocdepth to 1, I don't know if that still works in workarounds?

Comment: Which document class do you use? `article`? Do you stick to the traditional `\tableofcontents` command then?

Comment: I indeed use the `article` class. I have so far used `\tableofcontents` and looked at some other possibilities like `\minitoc`, which were not satisfying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible by redefining the commands `\l@section` and friends, which sets the entry for the table of contents, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tocpg@current}{}
\newcommand*{\tocentry}[3]{%
  % #1: level  name
  % #2: title
  % #3: page number
  \ifnum#1>\value{tocdepth}%
  \else
    \ifx\tocpg@current\@empty
      Page~#3: %
      \def\tocpg@current{#3}%
    \else
      \def\tocpg@new{#3}%
      \ifx\tocpg@new\tocpg@current
        , %
      \else
        \def\tocpg@current{#3}%
        . Page~#3: %
      \fi
    \fi
    #2\ignorespaces
  \fi
}
\renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{}
\def\l@part{\tocentry{-1}}
\def\l@chapter{\tocentry{0}}
\def\l@section{\tocentry{1}}
\def\l@subsection{\tocentry{2}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\tocentry{3}}
\def\l@paragraph{\tocentry{4}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\tocentry{5}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The example has increased `tocdepth` to 2 instead of 1, to get more use cases as the two sections, which are provided by `\Blinddocument`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of this sort in the [etoc manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) (section `A (crazy) inline display.`)

Here is a simplification. Notice that the section and subsection are well distinguished.

In this example, the headings themselves generated from the `blindtext` package contain extra information such as *section*, or *subsection*, which confuses a bit the TOC, in this inline style.

The TOC title itself could also be on the same paragraph (see the `\etocsettocstyle...` in the example from the manual).

The entire definition is put in a group, so that it is possible to issue `\tableofcontents` elsewhere and get the standard result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{etoc}

% cf more sophisticated example at end of Part V of etoc manual
% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc
\newcommand*\inlinetoc {%
\begingroup
\etocsetstyle{section}
   {\etocskipfirstprefix}
   {. }
   {\bfseries \etocname{} \emph{(starting on page \etocpage)}: }
   {.}
\etocsetstyle{subsection}
   {\etocskipfirstprefix}
   {, }
   {\mdseries \etocname{} \emph{(\etocnumber{} on page \etocpage)}}
   {}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\inlinetoc
\newpage
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: inline toc]