# Breaking lines in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

As a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266416/comma-separated-list-containing-section-names), I implemented an alternative Table of Contents, contained in an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\makeatletter

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newcommand*{\tocpg@current}{}
\newcommand*{\tocentry}[3]{%
  % #1: level  name
  % #2: title
  % #3: page number
  \ignorespaces
  \ifnum#1>\value{tocdepth}
  \else
    \ifx\tocpg@current\@empty
      p#3: %
      \def\tocpg@current{#3}%
    \else
      \def\tocpg@new{#3}%
      \ifx\tocpg@new\tocpg@current
        ,\ ~%
      \else
        \def\tocpg@current{#3}%
        ;\\p#3: %
      \fi
    \fi
    \uline{#2}%\ignorespaces
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
}
\renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{}
\def\l@part{\tocentry{-1}}
\def\l@chapter{\tocentry{0}}
\def\l@section{\tocentry{1}}
\def\l@subsection{\tocentry{2}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\tocentry{3}}
\def\l@paragraph{\tocentry{4}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\tocentry{5}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Section 2}
Test
\section{Section with long name}
More Test
\section{Section with even longer name}
\lipsum[3]
\section{This section has a long name}
Wow
\end{document}
```

This produces exactly the output I would want, but the packages `ulem` and `hyperref` seem to be interfering, and the `soul` package's command `\ul` is not working inside the ToC.

The problem of `\uline` is that it doesn't break lines in the ToC:
[image: ToC]

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the straightforward adaptation of my answer to your other question. The image shows the red boxes created by hyperref, as seen on-screen in certain pdf viewers (not all), they do not show up in print.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{etoc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}

% cf more sophisticated example at end of Part V of etoc manual
% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc
\newcommand*\inlinetoc {%
\begingroup
\etocsetstyle{section}
   {\etocskipfirstprefix}
   {. }
   {\bfseries \etocname{} \emph{(starting on page \etocpage)}: }
   {.}
\etocsetstyle{subsection}
   {\etocskipfirstprefix}
   {, }
   {\mdseries \etocname{} \ul{(\etocnumber{} on page \etocpage)}}
   {}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\inlinetoc
\newpage
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: inline toc with links and use of \ul]

To get the exact style you need, you will have to modify in the code above the `\etocsetstyle{section}...` etc...

Here is with addition of

```
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
```

inside the `\begingroup...\endgroup` of the definition of `\inlinetoc`, in order to hide the red boxes drawn by defaut by `hyperref` (but the links are still there).

[image]

### edit

Trying to use `soul`'s `\ul` more I hit against some problems. The work-around seems to be to use `\etocthename` which is expandable, and enough `\expandafter`'s to force its expansion before the `\ul`.

Then, this is wrapped up in `\etocthelink` to get the hyperref link. The example is again done with `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` locally, to not be visually confused from the red rectangles in the pdf display which overlap the underlining (notice the underlining breaks across line-endings).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{etoc}

% cf more sophisticated example at end of Part V of etoc manual
% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc
\newcommand*\inlinetoc {%
\begingroup
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\etocsetstyle{section}
   {\etocskipfirstprefix}
   {. }
   {\bfseries \etocthelink{\expandafter\ul\expandafter{\etocthename}} 
              (starting on page \etocpage): }
   {.}
\etocsetstyle{subsection}
   {\etocskipfirstprefix}
   {, }
   {\mdseries \mdseries 
% debugging: \typeout{\etocthename}
    \etocthelink{\expandafter\ul\expandafter{\etocthename}} 
    (\etocnumber{} on page \etocpage)}
   {}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\inlinetoc
\newpage
\section{a veryvery very very very very  long section title to test soul and
  its macro ul}
\subsection{inside the first section we find a subsection with a very very very
very long name}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not understand why some closing parentheses disappear altogether in the output. There are there in the expansion of the `\etocthename` macros, as expected.